# Switch to JDK 7 in Amazon Linux

Tags: java, linux, amazon-ec2, java-7

I have t1.micro 64-bit instance, where I installed JDK 7 following some instructions (`sudo yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel`)(`sudo yum update` etc). So, when I search for it,

```
sudo yum search openjdk
```

I get following-

```
java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
java-1.6.0-openjdk-demo.x86_64 : OpenJDK Demos
java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 : OpenJDK Development Environment
java-1.6.0-openjdk-javadoc.x86_64 : OpenJDK API Documentation
java-1.6.0-openjdk-src.x86_64 : OpenJDK Source Bundle
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
java-1.7.0-openjdk-demo.x86_64 : OpenJDK Demos
java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 : OpenJDK Development Environment
java-1.7.0-openjdk-javadoc.noarch : OpenJDK API Documentation
java-1.7.0-openjdk-src.x86_64 : OpenJDK Source Bundle
```

So, both are installed. But when I try to switch to JDK 7 using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

I get-

```
There is 1 program that provides 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
```

Why is it showing only the 6?

I tried other commands like-

```
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/bin/javac
```

but no success.

Comment: I'm struggeling with AWS at the moment too.. But with other stuff than Java.. Hope the +5 makes you smile at least one time this day :)

Comment: The `yum search` command searches for packages available for install If you want to see what's installed, use `yum list installed`.

Comment: How about marking the answer as correct or posting what worked for you?

Answer (score 13):

To ensure that openjdk 7 is installed, run below command.

```
# rpm -qa | grep openjdk
```

It should list 1.6 and 1.7 if you have both installed. If it lists only 1.6 (as in your case I would guess), then `sudo update-alternatives --config java` is working fine and you need to install jdk 7 by running `yum -y install java-1.7.0-openjdk`

Here is the output from my machine:

```
# rpm -qa | grep openjdk
java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.45-2.4.3.2.32.amzn1.x86_64
java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-65.1.11.14.57.amzn1.x86_64

# update-alternatives --config java

There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
   2           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:
```

Comment: Hi, the "rpm -qa | grep openjdk" command lists not 1, but total 4 - 6,7 and their "openjdk-devel" versions (probably, I installed -devel). But still the "alternatives" command only shows the one I mentioned. "yum list installed" shows all these 4 installed. "yum -y install java-1.7.0-openjdk" as expected, tells that it's already installed.